# PHP: Start Date - End Date range parsing by month

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I've got a logistical question here more so than coding one, but a code example/solution might answer both, so here goes...

If I have a form that I pass in PHP with start_date and end_date (full on m/d/Y format) and I need to print out a table of all entries in mysql database that fall in that range (so from m1/d1/Y1 to m2/d2/Y2) grouped by month, how would I even go about doing that in an elegant way?

For example, if I pass start_date = 5/20/2012, end_date = 7/31/2012, I need the resulting table to show results in this format:

```
May 2012  |  June 2012  |  July 2012
....      |  ....       |  .....
```

where the first column for May 2012 would show results from an mysql query like

```
SELECT ... WHERE signup_date >= 5/20/2012 AND signup_date <= 5/31/2012
```

and June 2012 would similarly show:

```
SELECT ... WHERE signup_date >= 6/1/2012 AND signup_date <= 6/30/2012
```

etc

So I am looking for a way to parse the start and end date into an array of dates properly arranged from the starting day of the month until the last day of the month, and if the end_date is a few months later then cover all the other months in-between in full (from 1st til last of that month), so that I can cycle through them in a for/while loop? So something like:

[0]['start'] => '5/20/2012'

[0]['end'] => '5/31/2012'

[1]['start'] => '6/1/2012'

[1]['end'] => '6/30/2012'

[2]['start'] => '7/1/2012'

[2]['end'] => '7/31/2012'

Any ideas?

Comment: mysql keeps date record in `Y-m-d` format instead of `d-m-Y` format

Comment: regardless, I can format it and reformat it in any possible way, so that's irrelevant... if it makes it easier, assume the dates are passed in Y-m-d format across the board.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$date = '5/20/2012';
$dateStart = date("m/01/y", strtotime($date));

$start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateStart));
$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateStart. '+ 1 month - 1 day') );

echo $start;
echo $end;
```

Comment: how will that show records for different months of corresponding years ?

Comment: That's how you get the start and end dates for your sql.

Comment: what if you use a GROUP BY MONTH(record_date) in your sql?

Comment: select * from table WHERE signup_date >= '2012-5-20' AND signup_date <= '2012-7-31'  GROUP BY MONTH(signup_date)

Comment: that is useful. but first of all , the first grouping should be based on year instead of month.

Comment: I've thought about that, but grouping won't work as I've gotta put these queries through a loop along with other queries... long answer short, just so I'm not explaining the rest of the code, I'm looking for some sort of a query which I could use in a for/while loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should be do achieve this with [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) . Sample code below.

```
<?php
$startDate = '05/20/2012';
$endDate = '07/31/2012';


$curMonth =  date("m", strtotime($endDate)); //End Month
$curYear = date("Y", strtotime($endDate)); //End Year

$months = array();
$months[] = array('start' => "$curMonth/01/$curYear", 'end' => $endDate);

while ("$curMonth/01/$curYear" > $startDate) {
        $monthEnd =  date("m/d/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $curMonth, 0, $curYear));
        $curMonth = date('m', strtotime($monthEnd));
        $curYear = date('Y', strtotime($monthEnd));
        $monthStart = ($curMonth/01/$curYear > $startDate) ? $startDate : "$curMonth/01/$curYear";
        $months[] = array('start' => $monthStart, 'end' => $monthEnd);
}

print_r(($months));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

See my comments first for mysql db date format.

written a bit in pseudo language

```
     $sql="SELECT * FROM ... WHERE `signup_date`>='2012-5-20' AND `signup_date`<'2012-5-31' ORDER BY  `signup_date`";


        $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $month_year=array() //3-dimensional array $month_year[year][month][primary_key];

    $month_index=-1;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    // find $month_of_the_date AND $year_of_the_date

    //find different months ,corresponding years, and db primary key and keep track in the $month_year array




    }

    for( all the years in the array ){

    for(all the corresponding months of the year  in the array){

//**EDIT:** you MIGHT need other loops and arrays to collect distinct years and corresponding months together

    // show the records with the primary keys corresponding to that month and year



    }




    }
```